# regex for unselecting inside selection

Tags: c#, .net, regex, c#-4.0, desktop-application

An example,

I have a string that contains let's say:

> function main {
>
> // TODO    print 'hello {cmd get
> world} world {nice}!'s asdads
>
> hello 'l{o}l'.'asd'
>
> }

How can I select only the words that are in within '''s and that are not inside a {}'s. This example would return the output:

match 1:

> 'hello {
>
> } world {
>
> }!'

match 2:

> 'l{
>
> }l'

match 3:

> 'asd'

thanks a lot!

Comment: I need all the work given in a regex, please

Comment: Can you be sure that the 's and {}s match?

Comment: yes, they need to be included

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood the question, I'm not sure what your groups are supposed to be.

Comment: the matches, match 1, match 2, match 3... sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just wanted all six matching strings separately I would use `['}].*?['{]` but you seem to want three strings in which case I would first replace `}[^']*?{` with `}{` and then match on `'.*?'`.

Comment: what do you mean, can you write the 2nd option in one regex, please?

Comment: by 2nd option I meant the one where it gives 3 strings

Comment: No, I can't do it in just one regex, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(myInput, "'[^']+'", RegexOptions.SingleLine | RegexOptions.MultiLine);
```

Now the trick is to only select the **even** indexes of the matches found.

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps - it has no relation to the `{curly}` blocks, and the OP needs all `'single quoted'` blocks. In addition, `SingleLine` makes `.` match new lines. `MultiLine` makes `^`/`$` match new lines. None of these are present in your pattern...

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you're after, in two steps:

```
IEnumerable<string[]> captures = 
    // Get the 'single quoted' tokens
    Regex.Matches(s, "'[^']*'").Cast<Match>() 
    // Split each token by { blocks }, but keep the curly braces.
    .Select(quoteMatch => Regex.Split(quoteMatch.Value, @"(?<=\{)[^{}]*(?=\})"))
    .ToArray();
```

The result is a collection of arrays of strings - each collection is a "match", and each string is a "group".

It is possible to do all of that in a single .Net regex, but it isn't pretty, and much harder to work with. Here's a working solution: http://ideone.com/qaceF , but I don't think it's a proper answer to the question when there are much simpler alternatives.